# Read USB-C ports using Java from MacBook Pro with Touch Bar 2016

Tags: java, macos, usb, usbserial

There is a library or so on to read USB-C ports from my MacBook Pro Touch by using Java?

My machine has four USB-C ports and an Apple USB-C multiport that "maps" three ports:

1) USB 3.1

2) HDMI

3) another USB-C

See [here](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1K2AM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter) for further details.

I need to read the USB 3.1 port thorough the adapter above mentioned using a simple Java program, in particular a tester device [this](https://www.dowarsztatu.com/product-pol-8026-Tester-czujnikow-TPMS-AID-CUB.html) (a TPMS AID CUB Tester) with a USB-out port that writes data, I have to read them.

I tried to use [JSSC](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scream3r/jssc/2.8.0) and the first example code form [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wikis/jSSC_examples.wiki):

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
     for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
          System.out.println(portNames[i]);
      }
  }
}
```

It runs without errors, but prints nothing, even if I tried to plug in a mouse.

On Wireshark I noticed it pings and my machine responds correctly to it.

---

Further details:

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you need to read? The storage of a connected USB drive? Or what kind of device do you want to connect to the USB port and read?

Comment: A tester device with a USB-out port that writes data, I have to read them. Question updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "a USB-out port"? What specific type of USB device do you have connected?

Comment: It is a TPMS AID CUB tester. See [here](https://www.google.it/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjulcOO-6faAhXG_qQKHQr0AMAQjRx6BAgAEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dowarsztatu.com%2Fproduct-pol-8026-Tester-czujnikow-TPMS-AID-CUB.html&psig=AOvVaw0Y8szcc7T2Ah7J1Jd8XCCp&ust=1523183426538922) or [here](https://www.dowarsztatu.com/product-pol-8026-Tester-czujnikow-TPMS-AID-CUB.html). Unfortunately I can not find more details online. It is used in a tire workshop.

Comment: @kitsune Do you know what type of device that is from a USB perspective, though? Most USB devices are not exposed over a serial interface.